# Why does this regular expression for sed break inside Makefile?

Tags: regex, makefile, sed

I'm using GNU Make 3.81, and I have the following rule in my Makefile:

```
jslint :
    java org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main jslint.js mango.js \
    | sed 's/Lint at line \([0-9]\+\) character \([0-9]\+\)/mango.js:\1:\2/'
```

This works fine if I enter it directly on the command line, but the regular expression does not match if I run it with "make jslint". However, it works if I replace `\+` with `\{1,\}` in the Makefile:

```
jslint :
    java org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main jslint.js mango.js \
    | sed 's/Lint at line \([0-9]\{1,\}\) character \([0-9]\{1,\}\)/mango.js:\1:\2/'
```

Is there some special meaning to `\+` in Makefiles, or is this a bug?

Comment: Any chance you have multiple versions of 'sed' on the machine and the one you use from the command line is different from the one used by 'make'?  The character that screws up shell in make is '$'; you need to use '$$' in the makefile to get '$' in the shell script.  Also, do you need to activate the extended regex syntax in 'sed'?

Comment: If I run `sed --version` on the command line, I get `GNU sed version 4.1.5` but inside Makefile it says `sed: illegal option -- -`. However, the target with `\+` still fails if I replace `sed` with `/usr/bin/sed`.

Comment: Are you running `make` from inside the same shell you're using when you give the command on the command-line?  I've had weird problems before when running `make` inside `emacs` due to environment variables being set up differently in a non-interactive shell (`sed` seems to look at some locale stuff, could these be different?)

Comment: @Jonathan, Yes I have indeed two versions of `sed` and the one in `/usr/bin/sed` seems to be broken (it came with Mac OS X). On the command line I found that I have `alias sed=gsed` which came from MacPorts and works with `\+`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\+` doesn't have any special meaning.  Also, there's nothing wrong with GNU Make, I suppose.

The expressions probably *does* match even in the first case, but the thing is probably that either

- you call `make jslnit` when a *file* `jslint` already exists in the current directory.  In this case it won't be considered as a target, for which the proper commands should be invoked.  To be sure, try inserting `echo` statement in your commands, just to tell Make got to executing them:

  ```
  jslint :
      echo I got here
      java org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main jslint.js mango.js \
      | sed 's/Lint at line \([0-9]\+\) character \([0-9]\+\)/mango.js:\1:\2/'
  ```
- your call to `java` yields different results (perhaps, it has changed?)
- **(this is the problem**, see comments below **)** the shell used by Make (it is `/bin/sh` by default, and can be changed as shown [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell)) and the shell you enter commands to (to check if both versions match) differ, *and* it in some way affects what you're doing.  For example, different default versions of sed are called in these shells, and in one of them `\+` is *not* equivalent to `\{1,\}`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but java is the same and there is no file named jslint. If I make two separate targets in the Makefile and call them jsplus and jscurly, then jscurly works and jsplus fails.

Comment: @pavel, The output from java is always the same, and I can always see it, only the `sed` replacement doesn't match with `\+` inside the Makefile. Different shell sounds most plausible so far, but I'm passing a string to `sed` which should not be mangled by the shell.

Comment: The `SHELL` variable on my command line contains `/bin/bash`, but inside `make` it's `/bin/sh`, which is different on my system. I tried setting `SHELL` to `/bin/bash` both inside Makefile and in the environment, but that didn't solve the problem with `\+`.

Comment: @jcrocholl, I might have been wrong about how to set shell.  Check here to be sure: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell

Comment: Okay, I found the problem: I had `alias sed=gsed` in my command line bash, and `/usr/bin/sed` is the one that comes with Mac OS X, and is broken. I'm marking your answer as correct because you mentioned different shell environments.